# Exception Handling in T-SQL - Multiple messages vs. multiple states?

Tags: sql-server

I've got a stored procedure that can fail for a number of reasons:

- A parameter has the value of zero.
- Foreign key violation in Table A.
- Foreign key violation in Table B.
- Unique constraint violation in Table C.

In terms of 'best practice', should I be using error states or error messages to notify the end user of the problem?

I know states are used to indicate where an error occurred in the actual code, but to an end user it's useless without some kind of documentation.

Having an entry in `sys.messages` seems overkill for every possible failure case for every stored procedure/trigger in the database.

So should I do this:

```
THROW 50001, 'Parameter value cannot be 0', 1
THROW 50002, 'Matching value not found in table A', 1
THROW 50003, 'Matching value not found in table B', 1
THROW 50004, 'Combination of values already exists in table C.', 1
```

Or this:

```
THROW 50001, 'An error occurred in the procedure.', 1
THROW 50001, 'An error occurred in the procedure.', 2
THROW 50001, 'An error occurred in the procedure.', 3
THROW 50001, 'An error occurred in the procedure.', 4
```

Comment: Depends IMHO. Some developers prefer generic error messages to not give away too much on the back end. Providing a detailed error message could allude to the db design and if the user was nefarious, provide them with information for sql injection. I'd handle input validation, and even sanitation on the front end. Granted the validation for your case can only really check for the first exception above.

Comment: The first seems much more likely to be maintained over time.

Comment: @scsimon, So the more 'secure' approach would be to use states and tell people to read the documentation if they need more detail?

Comment: It's really up to you. It's just my opinion but like Gordon stated... using the first will save you time in debugging and user support.